# Java Date implementation with unknown day, month and/or year

Tags: java, date, validation

Some real people do not know what day, month or even year they were born.

This can pose a problem for systems that require a full date of birth.

In the Netherlands the decision was made to code these birthdates with *unknowns*. The following is the birthdate of someone born in 1975, exact date unknown:

```
00-00-1975
```

How can I handle this in Java? I'm not asking about parsing a string of "00-00-1975" but an actual date implementation that supports unknown (maybe null?) values.

Thankfully, decision-makers wisened up in 2014, and now people with an unknown date of birth  are given a made-up date.
https://www.binnenlandsbestuur.nl/bestuur-en-organisatie/nieuws/niet-bestaande-geboortedatum-00-00-jj-blijft.9484714.lynkx

Comment: Damn good question !

Comment: @Zorglube This is indeed an interesting question ... and unfortunately not appropriate for SO. Asking for libraries and the like is off-topic here.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Subtly different, isn't it? "Is this thing in the standard library?" is not the same as "recommend me a library which has this"

Comment: @Michael Where do you see the question "Is this thing in the standard library?"?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose  I guess I was interpreting this part "*Does there exist any Java Date implementation*" to that effect, but now I've re-read it, it's not unambiguous.

Comment: I guess you'll have to build you own lib to handle that problem.

Comment: I can't tell you how often I've seen `01-JAN-1970` for obviously empty birthdays/anniversaries/etc in custom apps. This would be super-helpful, if easy to implement.

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is a good question with a good answer. @Ivana Edit your question to avoid asking for an implementation. Just ask “how to handle” to avoid this kind of knee-jerk close-voting.

Comment: *knee-jerk*: happening or existing as a result of habit, rather than careful consideration (for non-native speakers among us like myself).

Comment: You may declare a `TemporalAccessor` and assign a `Year`, a `YearMOnth` or a `LcoalDate` to it. For a completely blank value you probably have to create your own class, sounds doable to me. To avoid lots of `instanceof` operations you may use `isSupported(TemporalField)`.

Answer (score 5):

No, no such thing. You can implement your own, e.g.

```
interface Birthday {
    Optional<LocalDate> fullDate();
    Year year();
}

class UnknownBirthday implements Birthday {
    private final Year year;
    // ctor

    @Override
    public Year year() {
        return year;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<LocalDate> fullDate() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}

class KnownBirthday implements Birthday {
    private final LocalDate date;
    // ctor
    
    @Override
    public Optional<LocalDate> fullDate() {
        return Optional.of(date);
    }

    @Override
    public Year year() {
        return Year.of(date.getYear());
    }
}
```

Comment: Good solution. Could be further extended with [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) class for case where year and month are known but day-of-month is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to exploit the `TemporalAccessor` interface. Nearly all of the date and time classes of java.time implement this interface and certainly those classes that you would use for your uncertain birthdays. Declare a variable a `TemporalAccessor`, and you may assign a `Year` or a `LocalDate` or some other type to it.

Some programmers would be tempted to use `instanceof` a lot with such a variable, which may be considered not so nice. Fortunately for many purposes it also isn’t necessary. The `isSupported` method of `TemporalAccessor` can be used in most situations.

For a demonstration:

```
    // Example birthdays ordered from the best known to the completely unknown
    TemporalAccessor[] birthdays = {
            LocalDate.of(1955, Month.MARCH, 22),
            YearMonth.of(1978, Month.MAY),
            Year.of(1969),
            IsoEra.CE
    };

    for (TemporalAccessor birthday : birthdays) {
        String yearString = birthday.isSupported(ChronoField.YEAR)
                ? String.valueOf(birthday.get(ChronoField.YEAR))
                : "N/A";
        String monthString = birthday.isSupported(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)
                ? Month.from(birthday).toString()
                : "N/A";
        String dateString = birthday.isSupported(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                ? String.valueOf(birthday.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                : "N/A";

        System.out.format("%-10s %4s %-9s %3s%n", birthday, yearString, monthString, dateString);
    }
```

Output from this snippet is:

> ```
> 1955-03-22 1955 MARCH      22
> 1978-05    1978 MAY       N/A
> 1969       1969 N/A       N/A
> CE          N/A N/A       N/A
> ```

For a nicer interface you may wrap the `TemporalAccessor` in a home-made class. Your class could have getters for `Year` and `LocalDate`, for example, which could return an empty `Optional` or `null` in the cases where there are not enough data. You can think of more convenience methods. You know your requirements best, so I am leaving the details of the design to yourself.

Answer (score 1):

[Joda Time library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Partial.html) has `Partial` class which can be used to create dates with unknown month / day etc.

> Partial is an immutable partial datetime supporting any set of
> datetime fields.
>
> A Partial instance can be used to hold any combination of fields. The
> instance does not contain a time zone, so any datetime is local.

```
    Partial date = new Partial();
    
    // prints 1975
    System.out.println( date.with(year(), 1975) );

    // prints 1975-03
    System.out.println( date.with(monthOfYear(), 3).with(year(), 1975));

    // prints 1975-03-28
    System.out.println( date.with(dayOfMonth(), 28).with(monthOfYear(), 3).with(year(), 1975));
```